# Auction where each bidder bids on a bundle of items

Tags: algorithms, optimization, bipartite-matching

Is there some optimal solution in an auction where each bidder bids on a bundle of items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is NP-hard, by reduction from [3-dimensional matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching).

An instance of 3-dimensional matching involves three disjoint vertex sets $X,Y,Z$ and a set $T \subseteq X \times Y \times Z$ of triples of the form $(x_i,y_j,z_k)$.  The goal is to find a subset $T_0 \subseteq T$ such that each vertex of $X \cup Y \cup Z$ appears in at most one triple of $T_0$, and the cardinality of $T_0$ is maximized.

Given an instance of 3-dimensional matching, we can construct an auction with bidders $X$ and items $Y \cup Z$.  For each $(x,y,z) \in T$, we'll have $x$ bid \$1 on the pair of items $y,z$.  Now the optimal set of accepted bids for the auction is exactly the maximum 3-dimensional matching, so any algorithm to solve your problem would also solve 3-dimensional matching.

Since 3-dimensional matching is known to be NP-hard, it follows that your problem is also NP-hard, and in particular, there isn't likely to be any efficient algorithm for your problem.

The same reduction also shows that your problem is [APX-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APX), i.e., there is some $c>1$ such that there does not exist any $c$-approximation algorithm for your problem (unless P=NP).

I don't know whether there might be an approximation algorithm for some constant approximation factor.  It's [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching#Approximation_algorithms) that 3-dimensional matching can be approximated in polynomial time with a $3/2 + \varepsilon$ approximation factor; you might check whether any of those algorithms can be adapted to provide suitable solutions for your problem.  For instance, one very simple approach might be to find a [maximal matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Maximal_matchings) of the associated hypergraph; this will give a $1+k$ approximation, if every bid mentions at most $k$ items.  I don't know if you can find maximal matchings in hypergraphs in polynomial time, like you can in ordinary graphs.

---

### Practical algorithms

If you have to deal with this problem in practice, I suggest formulating it as an integer linear programming (ILP) problem and then applying an off-the-shelf ILP solver.

Introduce zero-or-one variables $x_i$, with the intended meaning that $x_i=1$ means that the $i$th bid is accepted.  Each constraint "at most one bid is accepted from each person" turns into a inequality of the form $\sum_{i \in S} x_i \le 1$.  Each constraint "each item appears in at most one accepted bid" turns into another inequality of the same form.  The objective function is a linear function of the $x_i$'s.  Now apply an off-the-shelf ILP solver, like CPLEX.

Comment: A reduction from exact cover is perhaps even more direct.

Answer (score 0):

Problem definition: There are k ≥ 1 bids. Each bid $B_i$ consists of a price $p_i$ and a set $X_i$ of integers. A subset S of the integers 1 to k is acceptable if $X_i$ and $X_j$ have no element in common if i ≠ j and i, j are elements of S. Find an acceptable set S that maximises the sum of $p_i$ for i element of S.

Remember all bids with $p_i$ ≤ 0. Then remember all bids where $X_i$ is the empty set, remove them, and later add them back to the optimal solution (someone is offering money for nothing; we take that).

Then remove any bid $B_i$ if there is a bid $B_j$, j ≠ i, where $p_i ≤ p_j$ and $X_i$ is a superset of $X_j$, until no further bids can be removed. Sort the remaining bids on $p_i$ divided by the number of elements of $X_i$ in descending order, so the most promising bids come first.

And now you do an exhaustive search: You either accept the bid with the highest ratio price / number of items or not (you have the choice). You then accept the bid with the second highest ratio or not - you may not be able to accept the bid if you earlier accepted a bid including any of its items. And so on. You record the highest price found so far. And you stop examining futher bids if you can prove that you are not going to beat the highest price.

Before starting the search, you would also try if you can extract independent groups: Create a set, starting with one bid $B_i$, then adding bids $B_j$ where $X_i$ and $X_j$ have elements in common until no more bids can be added. These bids can then be handled separately from all the other bids.

In your example: Bid 4 is eliminated because it's inferior to bid 1 and bid 2. The sets (Bid 1, 2) and (Bid 3) are independent of each other.

Comment: So, brute force?